# How to detect tcp disconnected in tokio sink item in tokio-serde library?

Tags: rust, serde, rust-tokio

I've found a library named tokio-serde which will send and receive data using tokio tcp socket and serialize and deserialize that using serde json.

There is two examples which will show how you can create a server and a client using this lib.

In this example you can see how to send data using `serialized` object.

```
serialized
        .send(json!({...}));
```

https://github.com/carllerche/tokio-serde/blob/master/examples/client.rs

So I've created a server app and stored `serialized` objects in a vector to send them messages later.
But for any reason, these connections can be disconnected and peer client may not be available.

Here my problem is how can I detect when a client is disconnected, using `serialized` object ?

I've searched through documentation but couldn't find any solution.

Any help is really appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: In general you'd get an error when reading or writing to the stream if the other side has disconnected. Tokio-serde looks to just defer to the underlying error type, which will be [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html#method.kind). Beyond that, you can probe it using [`.ready()`](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.3.0/tokio/net/struct.TcpStream.html#method.ready) on the `TcpStream` and detect any errors that way.

Answer (score 1):

As per @kmdreko comment. I tried to access underlying `TcpSocket` and detect the disconnect state using that.

Something like this would help to find if client is disconnected:

```
if serialized.get_ref().get_ref().as_ref().ready(Interest::WRITABLE).await.is_err() { 
    // Connection error
}
```

I know there is lots of `get_ref()` calls, but this is what I found for now.